# understanding Vue components and fileupload

Tags: vue.js

More reading on Vue components.
I don't understand the el property versus the name of the component.

The first two components simply use a template. The third seems to require the 'el' property. What should it point to? form again?

This gives me **onFileChange is not defined**:

app.js:

```
Vue.component('pg-title', {
    template: '<h1>ATS Credits and Debits</h1>'
});
Vue.component('pg-subtitle', {
    template: '<h2>Table:</h2>'
});
Vue.component('form', {
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            fileinput: ''
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createInput(files[0]);
            },
            createInput(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {

                vm.fileinput = reader.result;
                }
                reader.readAsText(file);

                console.log(this.fileinput);
            }

        }});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

index.html:

```
<pg-title></pg-title>
<pg-subtitle></pg-subtitle>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
</form>
```

Comment: OK, so I make a new element: sometext, and point the el at that. I still get the onFileChange is not defined error.

Comment: Appears I may have misled you at first.  Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just a few things

- You need to use `template` rather than `el` when creating components.
- Take the template out of the main document flow and use the corresponding component tag name as an element or use the `inline-template` property.
- Don't name components the same as any standard html tags.
- Data should be a function.

```js
Vue.component('v-form', {
        template: '#myform',
        data() {
          return{
            fileinput: ''
          };
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createInput(files[0]);
            },
            createInput(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.fileinput = reader.result;
                    console.log(vm.fileinput);
                }
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }
        }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-form></v-form>
</div>

<template id="myform">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
  </form>
</template>
```

With `inline-template`, remove `template` from the component and define your html like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-form inline-template>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
      </form>
  </v-form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that code outputs nothing, nor does it throw any errors.

Comment: @DaveC426913 I think you may be unclear on how the FileReader api works.  I moved the `console.log` so you can see that it works.  Just click "Run code snippet" and select a .txt file from your computer.

Comment: I've got it appearing in console.log no problem. I'm trying to get it output to the page.

Comment: @DaveC426913 I guess I'm not understanding the issue.  If you want the output of the file on the page then write the variable to the page with something like mustache syntax. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lswr9n59/)